# C# Creating an Index in a For Loop for an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I am attempting to do an assignment and I have attempted to try to record the results of two dice rolls by pulling the possibilities I could get from an array. Basically if I rolled a 2, 4, 5, 5, and 2,  I'd record I got two 2s, one 4, and two 5s. However, I am trying to figure out the best way to record it without having to resort to list every single variable 2-12. Might someone be able to assist me in learning how to make the shortcut for this from the code I provide? The code is as follows:

```
using System;

namespace Assignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Initialize variable(s).
            int diceRollNum = 0;

            //Create the array.
            int[] DiceResultArray = new int[11];

            //Create the random number.
            Random diceRoll = new Random();

            //Write out Headers.
            Console.WriteLine($"Roll\tCount");

            //
            for (diceRollNum = 0; diceRollNum < 36000; diceRollNum++)
            {
                //Roll the dice.
                int firstDice = diceRoll.Next(1, 6);
                int secondDice = diceRoll.Next(1, 6);

                //Add the dice sums.
                diceRollNum = firstDice + secondDice;

                //Record results.
                DiceResultArray[diceRollNum] =
            }

            //
            for (int i = 0; i < DiceResultArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i+2}\t{DiceResultArray[i]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are looking for specifically what happens under the Record Results comment. If anyone could help explain this to me, that would be wonderful!

Comment: Why don't you want to do this `var DiceResultArray = new int[12]; DiceResultArray[diceRollNum]++;` ?

Comment: That could definitely work though it might have been simpler to do what was suggested below. I just needed to understand how to make an index for the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few issues

1. `diceRollNum` is updated in the loop and it runs infinitely.
2. `Random.Next(minValue, maxValue)` generates a random value excluding the `maxValue`. Therefore to get a random number between 1 and 6 we should invoke `Next()` passing 1 and 7 min and max as parameters respectively
3. Should reduce 1 from `diceRollSum` (a new variable which stores the sum of dice values) when accessing the array, as the array is indexed from 0-11, not 1-12

```
using System;

namespace Assignment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            //Initialize variable(s).
            int diceRollNum = 0;

            //Create the array. 
            int[] DiceResultArray = new int[12];

            //As 1 is not a possible value for the sum of dice values, we can instantiate an array with 11 items and reduce 2 from diceRollSum
            //A slightly optimized Approach noted by Andrew
            //int[] DiceResultArray = new int[11];

            //Creates random instance.
            Random diceRoll = new Random();

            //Write out Headers.
            Console.WriteLine( $"Roll\tCount" );

            //
            for (diceRollNum = 0; diceRollNum < 36000; diceRollNum++)
            {
                //Roll the dice.
                int firstDice = diceRoll.Next( 1, 7 );
                int secondDice = diceRoll.Next( 1, 7 );

                //Add the dice sums.
                int diceRollSum = firstDice + secondDice;

                //Record results.
                DiceResultArray[diceRollSum - 1]++;
                
                //Slightly Optimized
                //DiceResultArray[diceRollSum - 2]++;
            }

            //
            for (int i = 0; i < DiceResultArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( $"{i+1}\t{DiceResultArray[i]}" );
                
                //Slightly Optimized
                //Console.WriteLine( $"{i+2}\t{DiceResultArray[i]}" );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 11 possible results with 2 dice: 2 to 12. If you want to save a little bit of memory, you can certainly use `new int[11]`, but then need to do `diceRollSum - 2` (to convert 2-12 to 0-10). But I'd probably prefer clarify over saving a few memory bytes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that @Andrew updated the solution by adding comments. So that OP can decide the best approach :-)

Comment: I think I'll aim for clarity as the code seemed to work well enough by itself, but I appreciate pointing out the flaws my code had. The optimization is definitely good, but not required here and I think clarity for the code itself is more important for an assignment like this. I think the choice to use either is great though! The concise answer was definitely grand! Thank you!